# error: while creating java package in a folder Javac: invalid flag :a

Tags: java, windows, cmd

I have a drive with name A and the windows cmd is not executing the following command i.e

```
javac -a a:\inspiron HelloWorld
javac invalid flag: a
Usage: javac <option> <source files>
use -help for the list of possible options
```

Comment: What do you expect `-a` to do? Because that's what `javac` is complaining about

Comment: What do you expect the `-a` flag to do? Did you mean `-d`? Also `javac` takes a file name, so it would have to be `HelloWorld.java`.

Comment: Is your file name really "HelloWorld" or "HelloWorld.java" and why do you use option -a? You can provide full path of file "HelloWorld" and `package` of "HelloWorld" so people can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `a` problems comes from the option, not the drive

```
javac   -a   a:\inspiron HelloWorld
         ↑   x
```

As from the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html) it isn't a valid option, you may use

- `-d` directory
  Set the destination directory for class files. The directory must already exist; javac will not create it.
- `-s` dir
  Specify the directory where to place generated source files